# Why aren't Android updates published simultaneously for all users in the same continent?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t the manufacturers updating the phone to the latest Android version when it’s available?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-arent-the-manufacturers-updating-the-phone-to-the-latest-android-version-wh)

Why aren't Android updates published simultaneously for all users in the same continent?

Comment: To not overload the servers, maybe? If all users would update at the same time, this would not only lead to high server load, but also result in slow downloads, which in turn users would complain about even more.

Comment: Most phones have per carrier custom firmwares (which need to get tested individually). Verizon for example is slow (delayed some Galaxy Nexus updates up to 3 months or so I heard somewhere).

Comment: Also see: [Are Android OS updates region specific?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16992/16575) / [What is Google's OTA phase deployment strategy?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57548/16575) / [Who are responsible for pushing out the OTA updates?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25603/16575) / [What is the typtical Android OS Upgrade policy?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39473/16575)