# I'm still waiting for Lollipop OTA on my 2013 Nexus 7

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

It's now nearly mid January. Can anyone suggest or explain why my 2013 Nexus 7 has still not gotten upgraded to Lollipop? I know that it's possible to manually flash the OS, but I'd figured I'd just wait. But this seems like it's really too long at this point. My Nexus 5 phone for upgraded the day after the now OS was released, and is now already on v5.0.1. On my tablet though I go to check for updates and it tells me my system is up to date (it's not btw - it's still running Kit-Kat).

Google searches return numerous posts from Nov with people griping that they hadn't gotten the upgrade immediately, but I'm not finding anyone else still asking. Most posts I'm seeing say that the upgrades are staggered out over a few weeks or so, but we're well beyond that now.

Anyway, just thought I'd ask around. See if anyone knows anything, or is also still waiting. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will my device get the Android 5.0 update (Lollipop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75684/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-5-0-update-lollipop)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. While that other post helpfully confirms that my device was supposed to be updated in Nov, it doesn't offer any explanation as to why I'm still waiting two months later.

Comment: You should also look at [What is Google's OTA phase deployment strategy?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/what-is-googles-ota-phase-deployment-strategy/57550#57550)

Comment: Anyone care to share why this was given a -1?

Comment: I can't speak for why the people voted it down, but this is from the [Help Center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote): Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

Comment: Ya - I'm familiar with the principles.  I don't believe the question contains wrong information or is poorly researched. Whatever ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/IGjuSEI6H_8

According to this thread (if you can wade through the ranting and flame), it does appear that there are delays in the rollout. A post from just this morning is asking when to expect the upgrade for the N7 2013.

So I guess I'm still waiting.

UPDATE:
fwiw finally got the 5.0.2 update yesterday.  So good.  And in answer to my own question, it looks like Google was holding back the 5.0 OTA for my tablet.

Comment: Add your answer as an edit into your question, for readability. You can always edit your own question. :)

Comment: @HasH_BrowN "Delays in the rollout" is a reason for not getting the update, so this belongs as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just flash it. The nexus is designed for the do it yourself type of geek. Or dump Android and flash a Linux distribution of your choice to it. Don't like it go back to Android. There are hundreds of easy to follow instructions on this process.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but I'm not interested in putting some Linux distro on it, and I don't want to flash an OS that Google might be intentionally holding back for some reason. Maybe that's my implicit question, is it actually being held back for some reason?

Comment: Google having a valid reason to be lazy? To save money? At the end of the day you own device designed to be hackable. Hack it as the Google gods intended.