# Not yet getting Android Nougat update

Tags: nexus-5x, 7.0-nougat

I have a Nexus 5X phone running Android 6.0.1  and I am not yet getting Nougat update. Is this normal ? A lot of people I know already installed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When will my device get the Android 7.0 update (Nougat)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139232/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-7-0-update-nougat)

Comment: It is said in that post that it should be available for Nexus 5X on august 22nd

Comment: Related: [What is Google's OTA phase deployment strategy?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/what-is-googles-ota-phase-deployment-strategy/57550#57550)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everyone got it.

If you want, you can sign up for beta https://www.google.com/android/beta and you will get the prompt instantly, or you can get the factory image and flash it in fastboot: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/bullhead-nrd90m-factory-61495c8b.zip

Answer (score 0):

[This person explains it best](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57550/188013), it is for an older version of android but I think they will use the same algorithms.

P.S. I still don't have it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link https://www.google.com/android/beta and the steps are explained their so it should be easy to take from thereof